# from PHP, how to make a jQuery button inside an HTML li element

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I have a PHP script that queries a database and returns the rows as li elements to a div in a jQuery Dialog. It does this by building an array in the PHP while loop that processes the query row responses. So far, so good. It displays a set of rows inside the Dialog in a div with an id=dialogResponse . It is the first two parts (2 rows of code) of the array instruction below. BTW, it is just li elements - there is no ul.

Now, I want to put a jQuery Button in each li response to give the user an action choice to inactivate/pause that posting. I'm pretty new at this, and I can't get a button to appear or anything to work. I get an Internal Server Error message so I can't tell if it is a selector problem, php syntax, or something else.

How do I get a jQuery button at the end of each li that will be the trigger point for a function that takes action on that row in the database? The event.preventDefault is a placeholder for a future function that will do a MySQL UPDATE on the selected streetAddress and city. Here's the code.

```
$messages[] = "<li> 
$storedStreetAddress, $storedCity  
"<script type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $( "#dialogResponse li")
.button( label: Pause posting).click(function( event ) event.preventDefault();});});
</script>"
</li>";
```

Please be specific and code helps a lot. I don't follow general instructions well in this area.

Comment: If you can't follow pseudocode or direction, you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Why does the `<script>` have to be printed in with the PHP? Why not have it included with in a JS file? For the button, why not create a standard HTML `<button>` [or whatever your preference] in each `<li>` and have jQuery target them for the actions? - You will need an `<a>`, `<input>`, `<button>`, etc. for the `.button()`

Comment: An internal server error is and error with the script. It could be anything that causes a fatal error in the interpreter. It's less likely that it's an issue outside of your script - but judging from what I see it's most likely a problem in your PHP. [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php) has some good PHP courses if it's syntax, looping, etc. you need to learn.

Comment: "a series of id=dialogResponse"? an id must be unique across an entire DOM document. repeats are not allowed.

Comment: @Biotox, your comment was worthy of acting on, thanks. I have the beginnings of it working, and just a bit of jQuery work to finish it. The Server Error message was caused because I used " throughout, rather than nesting with ' .  If you want to "Answer", I'll give you a green check mark. As I said, I'm a newbie, and I appreciate you "getting me unstuck".

Comment: @Mike_Laird I added it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does the `<script>` have to be printed in with the PHP? Why not have it included with in a JS file? For the button, why not create a standard HTML  [or whatever your preference] in each `<li>` and have jQuery target them for the actions? - You will need an `<a>`, `<input>`, `<button>`, etc. for the `.button()`